# Definition of generic point

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am trying to read a paper named D.S. Ornstein, B. Weiss, *Subsequence ergodic theorems for amenable groups*, Israel J. Math. 79 (1) (1992) 113–127, doi:[10.1007/BF02764805](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02764805). In this paper the authors have defined generic points.

> Let $(X,\mathcal B,\mu)$ be an ergodic finite measure preserving dynamical system. Then a set $B\in\mathcal B$ and a point $x_0\in X$ will be called **generic** if 
>   $$
> \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1_B(T^ix_0)=\mu(B)
> $$
>   and the same holds for all sets $B^\prime$ in the **algebra** generated by $B$ namely:
>   $$
> \bigcup_N\bigvee_{i=-N}^NT^i\{B,B^c\}.
> $$

I do not understand the meaning of the set $\cup_N\vee_{I=-N}^NT^i\{B,B^c\}$. Can someone help me out?

After defining the generic points the author say "As usual, we denote the common refinement of partitions (or algebras) by $V$." What did they mean by that?

Comment: The symbol that you've transcribed as $\lor$ and later as $V$ is actually $\bigvee$ and is being defined as "the common refinement". So $\bigvee_{i=-N}^NT^i\{B,B^c\}$ means the (coarsest) common refinement of the $2N+1$ partitions $T^i\{B,B^c\}$, where $i$ ranges from $-N$ to $N$.

Comment: @Andreas. Thank you for your answer. I want to ask you if there is some very natural way by which one can describe $B^\prime$? For example if $x_0$ is generic then clearly pointwise ergodic theorem holds true for the particular function $1_B.$ Is there a way by which the function space corresponding to $B^\prime$ can be described?

Comment: Take $\chi_{B}$ to be the characteristic function of $B$, so $1-\chi_{B}$ is the characteristic function of the complement. Now by taking products and using complements, one may write all the sets in that algebra by using those functions.

Anyways, that's far from being a research question and should be in mathstackexchange.